# Migrating blob field mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, migration, blob

first of all, sorry for my bad english, and sorry if post answered, but I don't found it.

I want to "migrate" `blob` field in `mysqli`, so, I want to get_records and store it in other database (with multiple connections).

I have the next table:

```
id | name | data | timecreated
1  | Foo  | BLOB | 1551863583
```

data could be a file(specially image, but not always)..

How should the insert in the database?

When I make the `INSERT` statement the value of that column is `null`.

A greeting!

EDIT: This is my code:

```
    <?php


$con1 = mysqli_connect($con1_host, $con1_user, $con1_pass, $con1_bbdd);
$con2 = mysqli_connect($con2_host, $con2_user, $con2_pass, $con2_bbdd);

function get_records_sql($sql, $con) {
    $ret = array();
    if ($results = $con->query($sql)) {
        while ($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
            $ret []= $row;
        }
        $results->close();
    }
    return $ret;
}

// Get records from foo_bar connection1
$records = get_records_sql("SELECT * FROM foo_bar", $con1);

foreach ($records as $record) {
    // Inserting records to foo_bar connection2
    $sql = "INSERT INTO foo_bar (`name `, `data`, `timecreated`) VALUES ('{$record['name']}', '{$record['data']}', '{$record['timecreated']}')";
    mysqli_query($con2, $sql);
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
}
```

Comment: How does your `INSERT` statement look like? Why do you want to keep files in the database after all? What do you mean by "migrate"?

Comment: @NicoHaase I edited the post with the code, thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: So, have you checked the generated query? Does it contain the expected information?

Comment: No, the query shows blob column as NULL

Comment: Have you checked whether it really contains data in the source table?

Comment: Yes, this is a portion of content: 
FFD8FFE000104A46494600010100000100

It's to large to paste all, but, yes, contains characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

I used as follow:

```
    // $r is an array, and have data record from con1.foo_bar

    $sql = "INSERT INTO foo_bar (`id`, `name`, `data`, `timecreated`) VALUES ('{$r['id']}', '{$r['name']}', ?, '{$r['timecreated']}')";

    if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param("b", $data);
        $stmt->send_long_data(0, $r['data']);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $id = $stmt->insert_id;
        }
    } else {
        $error = $con->errno . ' ' . $con->error;
        echo $error;
    }
```

Thanks for your replies!